# Replicate rows by value in column, change values to 1 or 0, in R

Tags: r

I have data structured as:

```
A B C D 

3 2 1 1
```

I want it restructured as

```
A B C D

1 0 0 0

1 0 0 0

1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0

0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0

0 0 0 1
```

Any thoughts on how to do this in R? Many thanks.

Comment: What is your input data: a named vector? a data.frame?

Comment: It's a data.frame.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is a data.frame, you could do the following:

```
coln <- seq_along(df)
m = do.call(rbind, lapply(coln, function(i) {t(replicate(df[1,i], coln == i))})) +0
```

This will result in a matrix like this:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    1    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    1    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    1
```

You can then convert it to a data.frame or set column names if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- rep(names(df1), unlist(df1))
dcast(data.table(nm1, v1 = seq_along(nm1)), v1 ~ nm1, length)[, v1 := NULL][]
#   A B C D
#1: 1 0 0 0
#2: 1 0 0 0
#3: 1 0 0 0
#4: 0 1 0 0
#5: 0 1 0 0
#6: 0 0 1 0
#7: 0 0 0 1
```

---

Or after creating the 'nm1', use `model.matrix` from `base R`

```
model.matrix(~-1 + nm1)
```

or in a single line

```
model.matrix(~ -1 + rep(names(df1), unlist(df1)))
```

and change the column names

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 3, B = 2, C = 1, D = 1)
```